# Kentico 13: Create new instance of ComponentViewModel and pass widget properties

Tags: kentico

I am converting old inline widgets from K12 content into static HTML.

To do this I am using `IViewComponentHelper.InvokeAsync` and need to pass in ComponentViewModel as a param but I also need to pass in the actual widget props from the inline widget.

However, `ComponentViewModel.Properties` is get only and `ComponentViewModel.Create()` doesn't offer IWidgetProperties as a parameter.

Is there any way to call InvokeAsync and pass in a ComponentViewModel with WidgetProperties?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var node = TreeNode.New(); //get a real treenode or it won't work
var args = ComponentViewModel<TPropertiesType>.Create(node, widgetProperties as TPropertiesType);    
var result = await _viewComponentHelper.InvokeAsync(viewComponentType, args);
```

`widgetProperties` are an instance of `IWidgetProperties`